# How to get this enum if I only have a string representation in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an enum class like this:

```
def enum(**enums):
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

payment_country = enum(    
AUSTRIA=7,
GERMANY=10,
SPAIN=20)
```

I notice all the usages of the enum are like this enum.payment_country.AUSTRIA.... etc.

I am getting the country names on the fly - they are a string - and I need to get the enum value associated with that string.

How do I pass in the country names to this enums module.

If I have

`country="AUSTRIA"`

then when I try doing `enums.country` or `enums[country]`,

I get this error message:

`TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__' or  AttributeError: type object 'Enum' has no attribute 'country'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getattr`:

```
getattr(payment_country, 'AUSTRIA')
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try `namedtuple` instead of trying to built enums...

```
from collections import namedtuple

CountryPayTuple = namedtuple("CountryPayTuple", "AUSTRIA GERMANY SPAIN")

payment_country = CountryPayTuple(    
AUSTRIA=7,
GERMANY=10,
SPAIN=20)

print payment_country.AUSTRIA
```

You can access named tuples either with `payment_country.SPAIN` or `payment_country['SPAIN']`. To get the fieldcountrynames: `payment_country._fields`.

EDIT1:

The simplest and more generic way would be using `dict`ionaries:

```
payment_country = dict(    
AUSTRIA=7,
GERMANY=10,
SPAIN=20)
```

You can access the country/field names with `payment_country.keys()`, but you can only access the payment-values by `payment_country['SPAIN']`.